# Curl request redirect

Tags: php, curl

This may be a redundant question, but i tried several approaches and still not found how to solve my issue.

I have a form and when submiting this one i'm redirected to page **A, B** and **C**.

**C** is the last page (another form to submit).

is it possible to handle redirections with curl and then submit last form knowing inputs and expected values?

Bellow my curl request (in PHP)

```
$curl = curl_init();
$base_url='https://xxxxxx.com';

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => $base_url.'?key=azerty&value1=87&value2=90',
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);
echo $response;
```

I'm getting html page.

Many thanks for your help.